# Multiple select statements in one, creating new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched everywhere and I can't seem to find the solution.

now I know the function of **UNION**, but I'm not sure if it is used here correctly. Here is my query:

```
  SELECT pos.pdPosition AS [Region 1]  
  FROM PositionData pos 
  WHERE pos.PositionId = 1765
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT pos.pdPosition AS [Region 2] 
  FROM PositionData pos 
  WHERE pos.PositionId = 1767
```

**What I want** is for it to create the new columns, Region 1 containing number 1's data and Region 2 containing number 2's data.

**What I'm getting** is this:

[image]

How can I split it up/what statement can I use?

**NOTE:** This has to be a select statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Select 
    (SELECT pos.pdPosition 
     FROM PositionData pos 
     WHERE pos.PositionId = 1765) AS [Region 1]
   ,(SELECT pos.pdPosition 
     FROM PositionData pos 
     WHERE pos.PositionId = 1767) AS [Region 2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one -

***DDL:***

```
DECLARE @PositionData TABLE (PositionId INT, pdPosition INT)
INSERT INTO @PositionData (PositionId, pdPosition)
VALUES (1765, 1765),(1767, 1767), (1768, 1768)
```

***My query:***

```
SELECT
      [Region 1] = MIN(CASE WHEN PositionId = 1765 THEN pdPosition END)
    , [Region 2] = MIN(CASE WHEN PositionId = 1767 THEN pdPosition END) 
FROM @PositionData
WHERE PositionId IN (1767, 1765)
```

***bummi query:***

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT pdPosition 
     FROM @PositionData 
     WHERE PositionId = 1765) AS [Region 1]
   ,(SELECT pdPosition 
     FROM @PositionData 
     WHERE PositionId = 1767) AS [Region 2]
```

***Output:***

```
Region 1    Region 2
----------- -----------
1765        1767

(1 row(s) affected)

Region 1    Region 2
----------- -----------
1765        1767

(1 row(s) affected)
```

***Query cost:***

[image: cost]

Comment: Again, shouldn't that be something like `(Case when PositionId = 1765 then pdPosition End)`?

Comment: Please convert `CASE WHEN pdPosition`s to `CASE WHEN PositionId` and `WHERE pdPosition IN` to `WHERE PositionId IN`

Comment: Why I need to do this? :)

Comment: Take a good look at OP's and @bummi's queries: they all filter by `PositionId` not by `pdPosition `..

Comment: @Snow Blind, my point is unchanged - please see execution plan.

Comment: I wasn't talking about performance, I was talking about the wrong filtering in your SQL. But you corrected it with the last edit anyway, +1 thanks for the effort.